# Spring Cloud Routing Function and SPEL Expression injection - CVE-2022-22963

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-function

I am having a springboot application and my local maven repository is having spring cloud dependencies present in it. I understand that for someone to use the CVE-2022-22963 vulnerability, the code should written to use the Spring Cloud routing function. Presence of the the spring cloud jar dependencies is alone not enough to exploit this vulnerability.

As per this link (https://sysdig.com/blog/cve-2022-22963-spring-cloud/),

The issue with CVE-2022-22963 is that it permits using HTTP request header spring.cloud.function.routing-expression parameter and SpEL expression to be injected and executed through StandardEvaluationContext.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, what is your question? You simply stating facts, some of them incorrectly, but nevertheless, what is it you are trying to find out?